# .Htaccess not redirecting to a subfolder in www

Tags: .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /reminder-app/

#Prevent Indexing
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

#Handle Controller

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /reminder-app/index.php [R=301, L]
</IfModule>
```

Im trying to redirect my localhost / to a subfolder called reminder-app 
i put .htaccess in www and that is my code. am i missing something because it display error :

> Server error! The server encountered an internal error and was unable
>   to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was
>   an error in a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500 localhost Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1

Comment: did you try without RewriteBase? It's smth different as it seems you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
with this this    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` So , don't use `$` in front of Server-Variables like `{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and use `%` instead.

Then this `[R=301, L]` should be like this `[R=301,L]` without space between `,`  and `L`

Clear your browser cache then test it .